# Run scheduled task only once on determinated hour in Python using 'schedule'

Tags: python, task, jobs, schedule, hour

I want to execute a scheduled task to run only once with the library schedule in python

The example i have is this:

`schedule.every().day.at(hour).do(job)`

It execute a task every day, but i do not want it to execute every day, just once, something like this:

`schedule.at(hour).do(job)`

Is this possible?

**EDIT**

This is my code for better clarification

```
for hour in sorted(list_of_hours):
    schedule.every().day.at(hour).do(task)
```

Comment: Yes.  I'm not sure you realize that, for that script to do its job. it has to run continuously.  Given that, you might as well use `time.sleep()`.

Comment: And, by the way, if you read the documentation, which you should, you'd see how to handle that task by returning `schedule.CancelJob` from the scheduled task.

Comment: In this case, i have a list of hours that i need to be executed, it's not one task but lots of tasks, how can i handle that?

Comment: You can also use the method `until()`. You schedule the job and you set the until datetime just after it. See https://github.com/dbader/schedule/blob/0bab53ea7f3b143d16888b54dc3bd43089450da9/schedule/__init__.py#L546

Comment: Linux and Windows both have an `at` command that schedules a job to be run once in the future.

Comment: I have updated my question, i have this list inside my code, how i can manage to use it with until() method, or schedule.CancelJob()? CancelJob only stops the executing job or all jobs?

Comment: I'd recommend using OS based tools to schedule.

Comment: There is a way that i can automate OS schedules jobs? For example, my bot generate the list of hours that i need for the day, than the bot also execute and schedule the generated tasks, but the tasks need to be run once, then the next day, it generate another list of hours and go on.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution of the problem, i think was not the best pratice but works well, making a counter that go througt the task, and ends comparing the quantity of hours in te list and the counter, like this:

```py
counter = 0
qtOfHours = 0

def task():
    global counter += 1

for hour in sorted(list_of_hours):
    schedule.every().day.at(hour).do(task)

while True:
    schedule.run_pending()
    time.sleep(1)
    if counter == qtOfHours:
        sys.exit()
```

Then to run it every day, i will use OS based tools to schedule the script, just like the answers before, thanks